# MongoDB connection with Pentaho Kettle (PDI)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I've just downloaded Pentaho Data Integration Community (`pdi-ce-6.1.0.1-196`) a.k.a. Kettle, with the goal of designing an ETL routine to make nightly migrations from MongoDB scheme into PostgreSQL.

I couldn't achieve the very first task: create a MongoDB connection. MongoDB is not listed as a `Connection Type` in the `New Connection` dialog, so I chose `Generic database`. Then, I failed to find anything related to MongoDB in the `Custom Driver Class Name` field required for the generic connection.

Is it possible that the installation/configuration went wrong with Kettle? I remember that I had to kill the first startup because it hanged forever.

Or does PDI-CE lacks some component that I must get somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDI handles Mongodb differently than other databases.

If working on a transformation (vs a job), go to the "Big Data" group of steps and there are two steps - one for MongoDB Input and one for MongoDB Output.

Within those steps you specify the connection information to your database.

Hope that helps,

Mark

P.S.  There is also a "MongoDB Delete" in the marketplace that comes in useful when deleting data from collections.

Comment: I was trying to build a Job. So I guess I should build the transformation first and use it in a Job later? the MongoDB Input worked fine here.

Comment: Yes - you will have to do it in a transformation and then if it needs to be a job, call the transformation from a job.  Glad to hear you got the MongoDB input working fine.